# Changing permalink for blog posts, current structure www.website.com/blog-post, change to, www.website.com/blog/blog-post

Tags: permalinks

I currently have blog posts on the website with permalink structure as -    [www.website.com/sample-post/](http://www.website.com/sample-post/). As Google indexing regards each of these blog posts as individual landing pages, I would like to change this to [www.website.com/blog/sample-post/](http://www.website.com/blog/sample-post/).

I modified the Permalink settings, under Custom Structure, I added, [www.website.com/blog/%postname%/](http://www.website.com/blog/%postname%/), and as to handle the redirects of the old pages, I used the Yoast Permalink Helper and added the redirect regex -

**RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/$ https://websitename.com/$1**

The previous blog post links show 404, even after following these steps. Any help?

Comment: Are your previous posts actually _Posts_, or are they Pages?

Comment: They are all Posts. As the earlier Permalink structure was www.website.com/%postname%/, all the blog posts have a URL similar to what a landing page will have. As to distinguish all of these posts, I wanted to add /blog prefix to the /%postname%/.